# Porting android apps for Samsung Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to port my application for samsung tab and i want to know what layout and resource should be keep in my resource file.what will be image size for samsung tab 10",7.1".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to read this article [Supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

There you can find the screen sizes and densities for what you are looking for.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i just want to add, never develop an app for a specific brand / screen size / hardware configuration when possible. In the case mentioned it would be simple to define different res/layout-xxx files to offer compatibility with a wide range of devices while mantaining simplicity